# How to define users and its roles in IBM websphere portal 8?

Tags: websphere-portal, ibm-rad

what I did:

**Step 1:**

> I have created five pages in IBM websphere portal 8. for example page0, page1, page2, page3 and page4.

**Step 2:**

> I have create 2 users, for example User1 and User2.

Now I want to give access of *page0, page1* and *page2* to *User1* and access of *page3* and *page4* to *User2*.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to ways to get page access configuration

1) Administration -> Access -> Resourse Permissions -> Pages -> Lookup
     page -> Press Key Icon

2) Manage pages -> Lookup page -> Press Key Icon

You'll see grid with access levels. Choose use User access level and press edit. After that you can lookup your users/grous and assign it to page.

Allow inheritance means that your page would inherit parent page access properties.
Allow propagation means that your page would propagate its access properties to children pages.

And do not forget press button Allpy before button Done.